# Recursively find all ancestors given the child

Tags: sql-server

Given a child id, I need to return a query containing all parents of that child as well as their parents till I get to the root parent. 
For example, given this data:

```
ID / Parent ID
1  /  0
2  /  1
3  /  2
4  /  0
5  /  3
```

So if I passed in ID 5 I would like to get a query with the results:

```
ID / Parent ID
1  /  0
2  /  1
3  /  2
```

This table does not work with a hierarchyid type so I suspect that this will need to be done with a CTE, but have no clue how. If it can be done in an SQL query / proc, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**This is more or less what you want:**

```
-- CTE to prepare hierarchical result set
;WITH #results AS
(
    SELECT  id, 
            parentid 
    FROM    [table] 
    WHERE   id = @childId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.id, 
            t.parentid 
    FROM    [table] t
            INNER JOIN #results r ON r.parentid = t.id
)
SELECT  *
FROM    #results;
```

**Reference:**

- [CTE: Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175972.aspx)

**Working example:**

```
-- create table with self lookup (parent id)
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT, parentid INT);

-- insert some test data
INSERT INTO #tmp (id, parentid) 
SELECT 1,0 UNION ALL SELECT 2,1 UNION ALL SELECT 3,2
UNION ALL SELECT 4,0 UNION ALL SELECT 5,3;

-- prepare the child item to look up
DECLARE @childId INT;
SET @childId = 5;

-- build the CTE
WITH #results AS
(
    SELECT  id, 
            parentid 
    FROM    #tmp 
    WHERE id = @childId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.id, 
            t.parentid 
    FROM    #tmp t
            INNER JOIN #results r ON r.parentid = t.id
)

-- output the results
SELECT  * 
FROM    #results 
WHERE   id != @childId 
ORDER BY id;

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

**Output:**

1 | 0
 2 | 1
 3 | 2

Comment: This is just awesome. The only tweak I made was to use the DISTINCT clause on the final SELECT. I'm not worried about performance due to the small recordsets I'll be working with. This filters out duplicates and just returns the hierarchies that I want, based on criteria I put in the WHERE clause of the first CTE query (not using id = @childId in my case)

Comment: Is it possible to use this with multiple childs inside the first query (above UNION ALL)?