# How find rows in one table that share common ancestor in second table with a third table

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the convoluted title, hopefully what follows is clear. Suppose I have the following tables:

```
T1
ID
1001
1002

T2
ID|T1ID
20|1001

T3
ID|T1ID
30|1002

T4
T1ID|T5ID
1001|2003
1002|2004

T5
ID|ParentID
2001|2000
2002|2001
2003|2001
2004|2002
```

T2 and T3 have a connection such that, via T1 and T4, if they share a common ancestor in T5, they are connected. In the example above, 20 in T2 has a connection to 30 in T3 because in T5 (via T1 and T4), they have a common ParentID, i.e. ancestor (2001). How can I construct a query that returns all rows in T3 that has a connection to a given T2? That is, given ID 20 for T2, it returns

```
T3
30|1002
```

T3 30? I know how to use CTE to solve something much simpler like "given T5 2004, find all ancestors" (2002,2001,2000), but I don't know how to extend that to solve this more complex problem. Thanks.

[Edit]

Using Paul Fleming's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598827/recursively-find-all-ancestors-given-the-child) as a starting point, I think I've been able to construct a query that works. But I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution. Working example for sample data above:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (id INT);
CREATE TABLE #T2 (id INT, t1Id INT);
CREATE TABLE #T3 (id INT, t1Id INT);
CREATE TABLE #T4 (t1Id INT, t5Id INT);
CREATE TABLE #T5 (id INT, parentId INT);

-- insert some test data
INSERT INTO #T1 (id) 
SELECT 1001 UNION ALL SELECT 1002

INSERT INTO #T2 (id, t1Id) 
SELECT 20,1001

INSERT INTO #T3 (id, t1Id) 
SELECT 30,1002

INSERT INTO #T4 (t1Id, t5Id) 
SELECT 1001,2003 UNION ALL SELECT 1002,2004

INSERT INTO #T5 (id, parentid) 
SELECT 2001,2000 UNION ALL SELECT 2002,2001 UNION ALL SELECT 2003,2001
UNION ALL SELECT 2004,2002


DECLARE @t5Id INT;
SELECT @t5Id = (SELECT t5.id from #T5 t5
inner join #T4 t4 on t4.t5Id=t5.id
inner join #T2 t2 on t2.t1Id=t4.t1Id
inner join #T1 t1 on t1.id=t2.t1Id
where t2.id=20);

-- build the CTE
WITH #results AS
(
    SELECT  id, 
            parentid 
    FROM    #T5 
    WHERE id = @t5Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.id, 
            t.parentid 
    FROM    #T5 t
            INNER JOIN #results r ON r.parentid = t.id
)

SELECT t3.* from #T3 t3
inner join
(SELECT t4.* from #T4 t4
inner join
(SELECT t5b.* FROM #t5 t5b
inner join
(SELECT  t5.* FROM #T5 t5
inner join
(SELECT * FROM #results) as R1 on R1.parentId=t5.parentId) as R2 on t5b.parentId=R2.id) as R3 on R3.id=t4.t5Id) as R4 on t3.t1Id=R4.t1Id
```

Comment: Can you please represent the expected results in a table to be more understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your tables, this is clearer I think:

```sql
DECLARE @T2Id int = 20;

-- Tree returns all #T5 IDs with each of their ancestors
WITH Tree AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId
    FROM #T5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT #T5.id, t.parentid
    FROM Tree t
        INNER JOIN #T5 ON #T5.parentId = t.id

)
SELECT *
FROM #T3
-- We don't mind if there are multiple common ancestors, we just want to find an example
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT NULL
    FROM #T4 AS t4a
        INNER JOIN #T5 AS t5a ON t5a.id = t4a.t5Id
        INNER JOIN Tree tr ON tr.id = t5a.id
        INNER JOIN #T5 AS t5b ON t5b.parentId = tr.parentId
        INNER JOIN #T4 AS t4b ON t4b.t5Id = t5b.id
        INNER JOIN #T2 ON #t2.t1Id = t4b.t1Id
    WHERE t4a.t1Id = #t3.t1Id
        AND #t2.id = @T2Id
);
```

Comment: Paul, thank so much for your answer. It is indeed clearer than my solution.